# Creating a measure by filtering a variable from a column in a table and subtracting its value by filtering two variables in two columns in Power BI

Tags: pandas, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a data table called `group_flows_t` in Power BI.
It has 7 columns as shown below.
[image]

1. From column C, I want to filter "inflow" Flow_type and get its values for Flow column (column F) for each hour (Time_str column). This gives the hourly_load flow.
2. From column C, i want to filter "unit_aggregate" Flow_type. from column D, I want to filter "Solar_PV" Group. and get its values for Flow column for each hour. This gives the solar_pv flow.

I want to do the same for "Wind" group and get the wind flow.

3. Finally i want to subtract hourly_load - wind - solar_pv flow and assign it as net_load flow.

The corresponding Python code for the above is assuming `df` as the data:

```
hourly_load = df[df["Flow_type"] == "inflow"]
hourly_load.index = np.arange(0, len(hourly_load))

solar_pv = df[(df["Flow_type"] == "unit_aggregate") & (df["Group"] == "SolarPV")]
wind = df[(df["Flow_type"] == "unit_aggregate") & (df["Group"] == "Wind")]

solar_pv.index = np.arange(0, len(solar_pv))
wind.index = np.arange(0, len(wind))

net_load = hourly_load.copy()
net_load["Flow"] = hourly_load["Flow"] - wind["Flow"] - solar_pv["Flow"]

net_load
```

How can I do the same in Power BI using DAX measure?
What are the ways to do them step by step as stated above? Can the net_load also be obtained all at a time using one DAX formula?

Comment: Are you wanting to create a Calculated Table or return a value?

Comment: Return a value from a table i'd say

Answer (score 1):

Create a Measure similar to:

```
Net Load = 
  var load = 
    CALCULATE(
      SUM(group_flows_t[Flow]),
      group_flows_t[Flow_type] = "inflow"
    )
  
  var solar = 
    CALCULATE(
      SUM(group_flows_t[Flow]),
      group_flows_t[Flow_type] = "unit_aggregate" &&
      group_flows_t[Group] = "SolarPV"
    )
  
  var wind = 
    CALCULATE(
      SUM(group_flows_t[Flow]),
      group_flows_t[Flow_type] = "unit_aggregate" &&
      group_flows_t[Group] = "Wind"
    )
  
  return load - wind - solar
```